# Add certificate to AWS EC2 client

Tags: java, ssl, amazon-ec2, certificate, aws-sdk

I'm using the EC2 java classes. To connect to an AWS account successfully, I have to add a certificate (.crt file) to the local Java `cacerts` file, using the keytool command, which works well when the code runs locally.
The problem is I need the code to run on a server, in which I have no access to the `cacerts` file, so I'm trying to add the certificate programatically, using the `ClientConfiguration` class. I uploaded my `cacerts` file to the server, the program reads it as a `KeyStore` object, and creates an `SSLSocketFactory` instance:

```
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, "<password>");
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfig.getApacheHttpClientConfig().setSslSocketFactory(socketFactory);
AWSCredentials credentialsProvider = new BasicAWSCredentials("<key>", "<private key>");
AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentialsProvider, clientConfig);
```

But it still produces the `HTTP Status 500 - Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated` error.
I have checked that the added certificate alias can be read successfully, with the keystore's `getCertificate` method.
The `"<password>"` sent to the `SSLSocketFactory` constructor is the keystore's password.
Is that the correct way to add a certificate to EC2?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the password parameter to the `SSLSocketFactory` constructor was not needed. Supplying the password to the `KeyStore` constructor is enough, and for `SSLSocketFactory` it's simply:

```
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
```